# libphonenumber js validating numbers from excel file

Tags: javascript, libphonenumber

I have a parsed list/array of phone numbers and i would like to check each one if "isNumberValid()".
i tried some stuff but i guess im missing something important because im a begginer..
How would i do this in javascript there is no documentation for js.

Comment: Do you know C#? If so you could use this port: https://github.com/erezak/libphonenumber-csharp

Comment: "i tried all kind of parsers but with no success." -- can you show some code that you tried?